# Characteristics and terminologies in database?

Tags: database, attributes, entity, field, record

I'm learning about database and I'm quite confused about some terminologies and charateristics of database. I'm looking forward to seeing the clarity of these terminologies.
I don't know if these are the same? (Fields and Attributes) and (Record and entity), if not, what is the relation between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These terminologies are just the same, however, in some details, it can be different. For example:

A field is a member of a dataset. An attribute is also a field but it should be public case.

An entity doesn't refer to anything in the database. It's using entity to refer to a conceptual object, whatever thing in the real world the database record represents. For instance, if you have an inventory database, each row stands for a product in the warehouse, and that's the entity. WHile a record is merely a rows of all fields